# Sum of angles in triangle is equal to $\pi$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I have to prove that sum of the angles in triangle is equal to $\pi$ using complex numbers. Can anyone give me some hints on how to do it? Thank you!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104829/using-the-complex-logarithm-to-find-the-sum-of-angles-in-a-triangle.

Comment: is there any more elementary proof than this?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** If the vertices of the triangle are represented by complex numbers $\ z_1\ $, $\ z_2\ $ and $\ z_3\ $, and the angles at these vertices are $\ \theta_1\ $, $\ \theta_2\ $, and $\ \theta_3\ $, respectively, then
\begin{align}
\frac{z_2-z_1}{\left\vert z_2-z_1\right\vert}&=e^{i\theta_1}\frac{z_3-z_1}{\left\vert z_3-z_1\right\vert}\ ,\\
\frac{z_3-z_2}{\left\vert z_3-z_2\right\vert}&=e^{i\theta_2}\frac{z_1-z_2}{\left\vert z_1-z_2\right\vert}\ , \text{and}\\
\frac{z_1-z_3}{\left\vert z_1-z_3\right\vert}&=e^{i\theta_3}\frac{z_2-z_3}{\left\vert z_2-z_3\right\vert}
 .\\
\end{align}
What happens if you multiply these equations together?